# fitbit php auth doesn't work

Tags: php, fitbit

After 10 hours of trying various fitbit php libraries I'm turning to stackoverflow for help.

This doesn't work: https://github.com/heyitspavel/fitbitphp

Using

```
 $profile = $fitbit->getProfile();
```

with that library returns

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'FitBitException' with message 'Your Fitbit request failed. Code: 400' in /var/www/api/fitbitphp.php:324 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/api/addFitbit.php(22): FitBitPHP->getProfile() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/api/fitbitphp.php on line 324
```

This the library on the fitbit website, seems like a lot of people have a problem with this.

```
    public function getProfile()
{
    $headers = $this->getHeaders();

    try {
        $this->oauth->fetch($this->baseApiUrl . "user/" . $this->userId . "/profile." . $this->responseFormat, null, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET, $headers);
    } catch (Exception $E) {
    }
    $response = $this->oauth->getLastResponse();
    $responseInfo = $this->oauth->getLastResponseInfo();
    if (!strcmp($responseInfo['http_code'], '200')) {
        $response = $this->parseResponse($response);

        if ($response)
            return $response;
        else
            throw new FitBitException($responseInfo['http_code'], 'Fitbit request failed. Code: ' . $responseInfo['http_code']);
    } else {
        throw new FitBitException($responseInfo['http_code'], 'Your Fitbit request failed. Code: ' . $responseInfo['http_code']);
    }
}
```

I tried this here as well but it doesn't return the user token or session id https://github.com/nostra999/fitbit-api

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps missed out the init step, as described in the lib README file (https://github.com/heyitspavel/fitbitphp/blob/master/README.md)

Simple working usage is:

```
<?php
define('FITBIT_KEY', '777'); // The application key registered
define('FITBIT_SECRET', '777'); // The application secret registered

$fitbit = new FitBitPHP(FITBIT_KEY, FITBIT_SECRET);
$fitbit->initSession('http://localhost:8080/fibit'); // callback URL
$fitbit->getProfile();
```

Also from the Fitbit API Documentation:
https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/API+Response+Format+And+Errors#APIResponseFormatAndErrors-Response

> 400 Bad Request Any case where either endpoint doesn't exist, resource
>   path parameters are invalid, POST request parameters are invalid or no
>   Authentication header provided. This doesn't include invalid specific
>   resource ids

If this does not help, please provide the full code that you run, not just

> $profile = $fitbit->getProfile();